# Pull multiple rows of data from 2 columns in several locations

Tags: text-processing, awk, printing, data

I have some really poorly formatted data files, and unfortunately the format of the files produced cannot be altered. I was using GAWK to parse the data into a manageable format but now I've been given a new set of files that use a slightly different layout.

Using the example below, I needed to find out if there is a way to pull all of the rows for the first 2 columns of data shown below " cell". I understand I can keep copying and pasting `getline; print $1,$2` but the number of rows can vary between 2 and 10000. Is there a way to build a loop that will read through all of the rows, stopping when it finds text or "=" instead of a number?

Ex. Data Set:

```
 1tally        8        nps =  2000000000       
       particle(s): neutrons 
       this tally is modified

 cell  20001                                                                                                                           
      energy   
    0.0000E+00   0.00000E+00 0.0000
    1.0000E-05   1.10650E-06 0.0213
    1.0000E-03   1.15086E-04 0.0021
    1.0000E-01   8.12322E-03 0.0002
    1.9231E-01   3.65758E-03 0.0004
    2.5000E+00   0.00000E+00 0.0000
      total      1.60091E-02 0.0002

 ===================================================================================================================================

           results of 10 statistical checks

1tally       38        nps =  2000000000
      particle(s): neutrons 
      this tally is modified

 cell  20001                                                                                                                           
      energy   
    0.0000E+00   0.00000E+00 0.0000
    1.0000E-05   1.10650E-06 0.0213
    1.0000E-03   1.15086E-04 0.0021
    1.0000E-01   8.12322E-03 0.0002
    1.2400E-01   1.20892E-03 0.0006
    1.4800E-01   1.00911E-03 0.0007
    1.7200E-01   8.39342E-04 0.0008
    1.9600E-01   6.99704E-04 0.0008
      total      1.60091E-02 0.0002

 ===================================================================================================================================

           results of 10 statistical checks
```

Current Attempt:

```
/^1tally.*[0-9]/ {print $2};
/^ cell/ {getline; getline; print $1,$2}
```

Ex. Output Format:

```
8
0.0000E+00   0.00000E+00
1.0000E-05   1.10650E-06
1.0000E-03   1.15086E-04
1.0000E-01   8.12322E-03
1.9231E-01   3.65758E-03
2.5000E+00   0.00000E+00

38
0.0000E+00   0.00000E+00
1.0000E-05   1.10650E-06
1.0000E-03   1.15086E-04
1.0000E-01   8.12322E-03
1.2400E-01   1.20892E-03
1.4800E-01   1.00911E-03
1.7200E-01   8.39342E-04
1.9600E-01   6.99704E-04
```

Comment: Would you show the output  that is expected

Comment: Would greatly benefit from having an example of desired output.

Comment: @RakeshSharma  Sorry, I've updated the question to show a desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# print lines from /energy/ to /total/, not inclusive
awk '/total/{p=0};p;/energy/{p=1}' /path/to/input
```

This will just set have `awk` set `p` to 1 when `/energy/` is seen, and set `p` to 0 when `/total/` is seen. The bare `p` (the condition that triggers the printing of lines) will then be `1` on lines which you wish to print.

This can be refined to print exactly the data you want:

```
$ awk '/total/{p=0} p==1 {print $1,$2} /energy/{p=1}' input
0.0000E+00 0.00000E+00
1.0000E-05 1.10650E-06
1.0000E-03 1.15086E-04
1.0000E-01 8.12322E-03
1.9231E-01 3.65758E-03
2.5000E+00 0.00000E+00
```

To also print the second field when you see `/1tally/`, just add a specific trigger:

```
$ awk '/1tally/ {print $2}  /total/{p=0} p==1 {print $1,$2} /energy/{p=1}' input
8
0.0000E+00 0.00000E+00
1.0000E-05 1.10650E-06
1.0000E-03 1.15086E-04
1.0000E-01 8.12322E-03
1.9231E-01 3.65758E-03
2.5000E+00 0.00000E+00
```

To put a blank line between each outblock block, use `/total/{p=0; print ""}`

Comment: is there a way to modify the `/energy/{p=1}` entry so that it will seek out '      energy' (6 spaces) instead of just 'energy'? This word unfortunately occurs in a dozen different locations but the spaces before it help to determine the relevant lines. If not could I still use the 'cell' string I was using before?

Comment: Certainly:  `/      energy/` hard-codes the six spaces into the search.  Though the formatting here compressed the five spaces into one.  slash, six spaces, 'energy', slash.  If that's the start of the line, this should work too:  `/^      energy/` (again, pretend there are six spaces there).

Comment: Perfect! That fixes my problem exactly. The additional command for the blank line keeps giving me an error message when I try to add it though. It is purely aesthetic for my use, but is there something I missed? I tried to use it by changing `/total/{p=0}` to `/total/{p=0; print ''}` but this appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Oh, of course; we're overloading the quotes.   Use `/total/ { p=0; print "" }`.